# dokuwiki: disabling versioning in dokuwiki

Tags: php, dokuwiki

i need help regarding dokuwiki
i want to remove versioning from wiki. any tip our help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance
I have looked into this code but so far didnt get any idea

`class cache_renderer extends cache_parser {
    function _useCache() {
        global $conf;

```
    if (!parent::_useCache()) return false;

    if (!isset($this->page)) {
        return true;
    }

    // check current link existence is consistent with cache version
    // first check the purgefile
    // - if the cache is more recent than the purgefile we know no links can have been updated
    if ($this->_time >= @filemtime($conf['cachedir'].'/purgefile')) {
        return true;
    }

    // for wiki pages, check metadata dependencies
    $metadata = p_get_metadata($this->page);

    if (!isset($metadata['relation']['references']) ||
            empty($metadata['relation']['references'])) {
        return true;
    }

    foreach ($metadata['relation']['references'] as $id => $exists) {
        if ($exists != page_exists($id,'',false)) return false;
    }

    return true;
}`
```

Comment: Do you need to remove versioning (which will require changes to the core system) or do you just not want your users to have access to it? (which can be done within the template)

Comment: i need to remove it from the system @symcbean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for the function saveOldRevision() in inc/common.php.

Btw. I would suggest to ask such questions in the official forum/mailinglist. There you'll find the people who know the sourcecode.